# Json Serialization is failing only in a single Service Fabric Actor with Could not create an instance of type

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, service-fabric-actor

I have a Service Fabric Actor service that, when a request comes in, retrieves and deserializes a document from CosmosDb, processes the request to update the document and then saves it back to CosmosDb.

Yesterday one of the Actors started throwing the following exception:
Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
Failed Method: Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject
Message: Could not create an instance of type . Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path , line 1, position 1211.

It is only the one Actor that is throwing this exception.  There are hundreds more that are handling the serialization just fine. And over the last 12 months the system has probably handled of 100,000 such documents.

I have been taken a copy of the document from CosmosDb and tested that it can be deserialized correctly.
I have also ran unit tests against the code that retrieves and deserializes the document.

I cant find any issues with the document itself or the code.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this single actor to throw this exception?

Comment: It all depence on the code, this looks a bit like you have some kind of meganism that takes in a type, the question is how does it get the type. If it's generated based on some database field, you want to check which types are used. Probably one is a interface or a abstract class.

Comment: I actually think the exception being thrown is a little misleading.  All the type information is stored in the json document.  I have proved that it can be deserialized successfully and there are thousands of documents with identical structure using the same type that have never had an issue